# Why did they decide to eliminate Mamoru?

Tags: from-the-new-world

### Warning: spoilers of the second season.

The education committee decides to eliminate Mamoru, and sends the Impure Cats against him, but fail.

> It then leads to him and Maria escaping and triggers the whole mess with the monster rat revolution.

The Education Committee is scolded for attempting to eliminate Mamoru and also for failing to do so.

But why did they decide that Mamoru had to be eliminated in the first place?

Comment: He has subpar control of Cantus, iirc. It would danger the society with his poor control of Cantus.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to eliminate Mamoru, the committee had already gotten rid of a girl named [Reiko](http://shinsekaiyori.wikia.com/wiki/Reiko_Amano), who belonged in the same group as Saki and the others.

The reason they killed her was [due to her poor control of Cantus](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4130/13330), out of fear of Fiends and Karma Demons. In this particular case, it's the fear of Karma Demons and their inability to control their Cantus, leading to unconsciously and involuntarily destroying their surroundings.

Mamoru had similarly weak Cantus. Though not quite as bad as Reiko's, the committee feared he might become a Karma Demon because of this.

Comment: this doesn't answer why Mamoru was to be eliminated.

Comment: @Pinocchio. Sorry, I though it was obvious enough without me pointing out the parallels. I edited my answer.